# refresh an array without refreshing the page in angularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array that I want to affect to it data that I have get from my Factory,but when I try to access it I don't get the data recently added to it,this the array when I try to fill it whith data:

```
$scope.copyofOpList = [];
    $scope.UpdateOperations = function() {
                         $scope.copyofOpList = gammeOfFactory.getListOperations();
                        }
```

this is my Factory from which I get the Data:

```
.factory(
    'gammeOfFactory',
    function($http, $q) {

        var backObject = {
            getListOperations: _getListOperations
        }

        return backObject;

        //used to get list of operations from ws
        function _getListOperations() {

            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "MyWebService/getAll"
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                defer.resolve(response.data);
            }, function myError(response) {
                deferred.reject('Erreur into url ' + response);
            });

            return defer.promise;
        };
    });
```

so please,how can I refresh the Data in this array without refreshing the web page
thanks for help

Comment: add a refresh button that calls `UpdateOperations`?

Comment: yes Sir How can I update the values in $scope.copyofOpList without refreshing the page??